# Persistent Calculated Fields in Django

Tags: python, django

In MS SQL Server there is a feature to create a calculated column: a table column that is calculated on the fly at retrieval time. This more-or-less maps on to using a method on a Django model to retrieve a calculated value (the common example being retrieving Full Name, based on stored Forename/Surname fields).

For expensive operations, SQL Server provides a `Persisted` option. This populates the table column with the results of the calculation, and updates those results when the table is updated - a very useful feature when the calculation is not quick but does not change often compared to access.

However, in Django I cannot find a way to duplicate this functionality. Am I missing something obvious? My best guess would be some sort of custom Field that takes a function as a parameter, but I couldn't see a pre-existing one of those. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is just to use a regular model field that is calculated whenever an object is saved, e.g.,:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    # This is your 'persisted' field
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # set the full name whenever the object is saved
        self.full_name = '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.surname)
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You could make this special field [read-only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) in the admin and similarly [exclude it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use) from any model forms.

Comment: I am apparently an idiot. This is a great way of solving the problem. I would amend it slightly though and hook into the save signals, as I need the field to be recalculated on inserts and deletes (depends on the number of entries). But yes this approach is in essence correct.

Comment: I would set `editable=False` since the value will be set programmatically (not by a form). Or (more better) use [GeneratedField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#generatedfield)